# Dropdown search from database, get images for different model/brand and display it

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

My problem is to display an image that is associated with the mysql results... Say the result has ID=250 and Name=brand.model, then I want a piece of code to search in a folder for an image with the name id_brand.model.jpg on the server.

Database structure is id, master, name. When user selects Brand + Model from dropdown it should get image from folder (could also get image from database, which one is better nowadays) and images all have unique name's what should be echoed as part name.

(Pictures to help understanding what i mean https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTCxs.jpg )

Here's pastebin's to what i have coded yet. 
http://pastebin.com/kQF2qP64

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What can't you do? Anyway, see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.dir.php

Comment: I'm not so experienced with PHP / MySQL / JS so i'm having trouble writing the code.

Comment: And you want us to wirte a code to you for free? Awesome.

Comment: Not really, just a little help to get started.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to bind the `change` event of the `select` to send the name to a function to search the file, then append the file/s to the DOM:

### Javascript (Ajax)

```
// Every time a category is selected we request the files
$('#category').on('change', function() {
    // If we have an element with images loaded, lets delete it
    var searchResult = $("#search-result").empty();
    // Now we serialize the form data, add an id to the form
    var searchBrand = $('#gender').find('option:selected').text();
    var searchModel = $('#category').find('option:selected').text();
    var fileName = searchBrand + '.' + searchModel + '.jpg';
    var searchData = { filename: fileName }
    // Now we create the ajax request with the form data
    var request = $.getJSON('search_images.php', searchData);
    // If the request success we show the images
    request.done(function(data) {
        // For each image found we add a new image to the DOM
        $.each(data, function(index, image_uri) {
            // First let's create the image element
            var img = $("<img>", {
                "class": "result-image",
                "src": image_uri
            });
            // Then we append it to the DOM
            searchResult.append( img );
        });
    });
    // If the search fails, we notify that no results were found
    request.fails(function() {
        alert('No results found');
    });
});
```

#### PHP (search_images.php)

```
<?
// Get the file name
$filename = $_GET['filename'];
// Find all the images
$images = glob("images/file/path/*_{$filename}");
// Return the images as json
echo json_encode($images);
```

Comment: @sknnndz just a question, if you select stuff, it may return several images?

Comment: Yes, it's supposed to find all the images for models for example user chooses Alfa Romeo -> Giulia it gets all the images from folder which has all the images for that model

Comment: Oh, so you do need some ajax to get this work, in that case it will find all images with this file name pattern: `*_alfaromero.giulia.jpg`? for example

Comment: Yes, exactly like that!

Comment: @axel-a-grazx Hi dude, i've been trying to get that code working but i'm having a bit of a problem. Could you help me more?